# How can I apply color to a grayscale image?

Tags: color, adobe-fireworks

I'm using Fireworks for graphical drawing, and I have this bitmap image that contains some greys that I wish to change it to red, however if I use the Hue/Saturation on it, it does not change colour.

What is the best method to change grey to red?

Answer (score 8):

the very definition of gray is that its lacking any hue. If there is no hue, there's no way to adjust saturation.

That said, most image editing software has a checkbox in the hue adjustment dialogue labeled 'colorize' that will do exactly as you want...it will give the gray a hue of your preference.

Comment: +1 for Colorize, I missed that many a time in my design infancy lol